# Nonlinearly constrained maximization problem using MathProgBase in Julia

Tags: julia

The objective function is f(x,y)=sqrt(x^2+2*y^2-xy), subject to 10 > x > 0, 10 > y > 0, x > y. I am going to find the x and y which maximize objective function. I am required to use Nonlinear models in MathProgBase.jl packages. The tutorial from https://mathprogbasejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nlp.html is difficult for me to follow since I am a beginner. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743136/how-can-i-make-strict-constraint-in-the-julia-jump-software) that JuMP doesn't support strictly greater/lower constraints (as result that most solver engines doesn't either).

A modellisation in Julia of your problem would be:

```
using JuMP, Ipopt

m = Model(with_optimizer(Ipopt.Optimizer, print_level=0))

@variable(m, 0 <= x <= 10, start=1)
@variable(m, 0 <= y <= 10, start=1)

@constraint(m, c1,     y <= x )

@NLobjective(m, Max, sqrt(x^2+2*y^2-x*y))

optimize!(m)

status = termination_status(m)

if (status == MOI.OPTIMAL || status == MOI.LOCALLY_SOLVED || status == MOI.TIME_LIMIT) && has_values(m)
    if (status == MOI.OPTIMAL)
        println("** Problem solved correctly **")
    else
        println("** Problem returned a (possibly suboptimal) solution **")
    end
    println("- Objective value : ", objective_value(m))
    println("- Optimal solutions:")
    println("x: $(value.(x))")
    println("y: $(value.(y))")
else
    println("The model was not solved correctly.")
    println(status)
end
```

(see https://lobianco.org/antonello/personal/blog/2017/0203_jump_for_gams_users for an explanation of the various steps)

That results of the script is:

```
** Problem returned a (possibly suboptimal) solution **
- Objective value : 14.14213575988668
- Optimal solutions:
x: 10.0
y: 10.0
```